# Custom Angular Theme/ Schematic on Azure Devops Artifacts

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We make use of artifacts on Azure Devops. From googling I have gathered https://angular.io/cli/new that an option can be provided for --collection=collection (A collection of schematics to use in generating the initial app). Is it possible to publish this collection to npm on azure devops or another private repo for use as a boilerplate template in our development.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the collection is actually a regular npm package of the form that npmjs.org would accept, Azure Artifacts should be able to store it the same as any other npm package. Otherwise, it will not.